# Can't Connect to World of Tanks server after an update to v.0.9.19.1 #487

Tags: technical-issues, world-of-tanks

I installed the Mac Wrapper for WoT and played for a couple of months. A few days ago the game updated itself to

> version v.0.9.19.1 #487

Suddenly it stopped being able to connect to WoT servers. When I press the connect button the spinner appears with the word "Connecting" and after a long while it ends with the warning that it failed to connect to the server. I haven't been able to play since the update.

Is there a way to debug this? Are logs kept anywhere?

Comment: Do you have computer specs. Is Mac Wrapper up to date? What happens when you disable Mac Wrapper. BTW, logs are kept in "WOTLauncher.log.bak" use a basic text editor to view it.

Comment: I've redownloaded the wrapper so it should be the latest version. My laptop is a Macbook Pro from 2013. I'll check the logs.

Comment: @KingsleyZhong I can't find any logs.

Comment: So you can't find the file or is there nothing in it?

Comment: Can't find the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (temporary) enabling file sharing on your Mac. Worked for me after finding this at http://forum.worldoftanks.com/index.php?/topic/549495-9191-client-issues-please-post-here/page__st__120#topmost

Comment: It's best to include the relevant information from a link in case it ever goes dead. I'm not sure if there's more in-depth information there, but if there is, you should add it to your answer.

Comment: @Vemonus all the relevant info is that toggling the file sharing during the login phase unblocks the latest WoT on mac.